# SQL Server : selecting multiple columns into multiple variables in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

The following works in MySQL:

```
DECLARE myInt INT(20);
DECLARE myDate DATETIME;

SELECT someInt, someDate
INTO myInt, myDate
FROM someTable
WHERE myName = someName
```

Is it possible to do something like that in SQL Server?

SQL Server complaints about "Incorrect syntax" in the `INTO` line f that is attempted local @variables.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your issue. If you want to set multiple variables at once:

```
DECLARE @myInt INT;
DECLARE @myDate DATETIME;

SELECT @myInt = someInt, @myDate = someDate
FROM someTable
WHERE myName = someName
```

Also note if the select fetches many rows the variables will hold the last rows values. In fact the variables will be set for each row fetched.

Also note in **SQL Server** you don't have a parameter to the `Int` declaration. Maybe you want to use [Decimal(20)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx).

Comment: To clafify the remark about the `int` declaration, in SQL Server `int` is a 32-bit integer, and `bigint` is a 64-bit integer, so if you need a different precision then you can use the `decimal` type.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, do it like below. Also, prefix `@` sign for declaring parameter.

```
DECLARE @myInt INT;
DECLARE @myDate DATETIME;

SELECT @myInt = someInt, @myDate = someDate
FROM someTable
WHERE myName = someName
```